# Issue with updating a user's information in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Please i'm going nuts on this thing.

I have this form:

```
echo "<input type='text'  name='user_id' value='".$id."'' />";
    echo "<tr><td>Emer</td><td><input type='text'  name='first_name' value='".$rows['first_name']."' /></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Mbiemer</td><td><input type='text' name='last_name' value='".$rows['last_name']."'' /></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Mosha</td><td><input type='text' name='age' value='".$rows['age']."' /></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Nr.Telefoni (Nr. i telefonit duhet te jete i formatit 06* ** *** **)</td><td><input type='text' name='phone' value='".$rows['phone']."' /></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>E-mail</td><td><input type='text' size='25' name='email' value='".$rows['Email']."' /></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Qyteti</td><td><input type='text' size='25' name='city' value='".$rows['city']."' /></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Shteti</td><td><input type='text' size='25' name='country' value='".$rows['country']."' /></td></tr>";
```

The update code:

```
    $first_name= $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name= $_POST['last_name'];
    $mosha= $_POST['age'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];
        $id = $_POST['user_id'];

$query = "UPDATE users SET first_name = '$first_name',last_name = '$last_name',age = '$mosha',phone = '$phone',Email = '$email',country = '$country',city = '$city' WHERE user_id = '$id' ";
    mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
    ;
```

If i echo it i get this:

```
UPDATE users SET first_name = 'Al',last_name = 'M',age = '22',phone = '3545435345',Email = 'albana@al.com',country = 'Albania',city = 'Tirana' WHERE user_id = '1'
```

Then the issue is, i go back to the page where i have all users and the phone number there displays something totally different, it's like a fixed number.
Please help me where i'm going wrong!
Is driving me nuts.

The query:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM users WHERE Active = 1 AND user_id="'.$id.'"';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

Phone number is integer type.

Comment: what is data type of phone ? show us code where you are getting fixed number

Comment: What select query are you using to get 'rows'?

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated. Use either POS or mysqli_*

Comment: Also: Make sure that you ESCAPE those inputs. `mysqli_real_escape_string` does wonders against SQL-injections.

Comment: I have updated the question, look at it please..

Comment: Well, first i'll make it work then i'll worry about sql injection :)

Comment: what is size of int for phone ?

Comment: While I can see where you're coming from, you could accidentally be killing your query by using unescaped signs.

Comment: @Alb: You have _bigger_ problems with your code. SQL injection for example. Someone can easily blank out _all_ user records.

Comment: Can i prevent SQL Injection by escaping the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it displays as `2147483647`, then it'll be the data type problem use varchar(10) if the phone number starts with 0 or + otherwise use bigint

Comment: Thanks, you saved me, it was exactly what it was outputting! Thank you very very much :)